# Tumblr adds "denied" to the beginning of Skype URI link in a caption

Tags: html, tumblr, skype, skype-uri.js

I was trying to include a Skype URI link in a Tumblr caption like so:
   skype:echo123?chat

But when I submitted the post, the link was:
    denied:skype:echo123?chat

I've included Skype links in the past this way with no problem, so I have no idea why I can't do it with this post. I've used different Skype accounts, removed "chat" and made it "call" instead, and the same thing happens.

Where is this "denied" coming from, what does it mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hey! This is so weird. I have never seen this issue until now. I am seeing it with hyperallergenic links. So it seems to be some sort of blacklist of domains.

Comment: OK, I think it was merely because of a malformed URL. I went into the post and could see that there were some HTML entities on the end of the url, so I think tumblr must automate that to block the link as it should not contain certain characters. Once I edited the post the link worked fine. I think in your case you won't be able to create a link which does not start with `http` or `mailto`, fairly certain tumblr would block other protocols.